# How to prevent old git revert showing up in each branch

Tags: git, github, revert

I just realised my revert commit 2 months old is showing up on each pull request in Commits section. Also, it seems all master merges after it are shown, so I have like 28 commits prior to actual changes in each PR

How can I prevent this?

Can I do it using `git pull -rebase` on master branch?

Is it advisable to remove master branch locally and then pull it from remote?

NOTE: I cannot push to master directly since it's a company repo

Comment: Switch to your local `master` branch, then rename it `git branch -m master-old`. Pull the latest `master`, switch to it and move on. You can delete the old `master` whenever you want.